# Difference between "Walk" and "Walk down" / "Drive" and "Drive down"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'm an English learner, and sometimes I cannot understand why some words are used to express a meaning. For example, the word "Down". What's the difference between "I walked on the street" and "I walked down the street" or "Alan drove down the street" and "Alan drove on the street" ?? As far as I know, these verbs are not phrasal verbs, so how can I know when to add this "adverb particle-like" with a verb ?

Comment: For *walk*, there's not much difference. But if you say "He did cartwheels down the street," it means that as he does the cartwheels, he progresses along the street. If you say "He did cartwheels on the street," it just means that he's doing cartwheels in the the street, not that he is moving along the street while he's doing the cartwheels.

Answer (score 2):

**on the street** refers to the street as a surface.  **down the street** refers to the street as something with length. When you drive down the street, you drive *along* it.

Comment: _Down the street_ involves a vanishing-point visual image, where things get smaller as they are farther away. That's the _down_ part - small.

Comment: I am skeptical that there's some notion of a *vanishing point visual image* when someone says "I drove down the street".  The word has been used of traveling on the open sea and on open fields where the visual image is one of an *expanse*. I think there's a notion of distance, but not necessarily of things getting smaller they farther away they are. Where do you get this link between "down" and "small"?